# Can I use Tensorflow.js with Express framework?

Tags: node.js, express, tensorflow

I am building a job search platform in express.js framework so I want to use machine learning for search function. I came in contact with tensorflow.js whenwhen I was searching to find solution.
My question is can i use Tensorflow.js with Expressjs framework ? Or any other solution which has resources on internet about executing machine learning with express.js framework?

Answer (score -1):

Simple `nodejs` script that starts `express` server and uses toxicity `tensorflowjs` model.

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const toxicity = require('@tensorflow-models/toxicity');
const express = require('express');

const threshold = 0.9;
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

async function runServer() {
  const model = await toxicity.load(threshold);
  const app = express();

  app.use(express.json());

  app.post('/prediction', (req, res) => {
    model.classify([req.body.sentence]).then((predictions) => {
      // Send the response to the user
      res.json({
        predictions,
      });
    });
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`);
  });
}

runServer();
```

[Source](https://juandes.com/tensorflowjs-node-cloudrun/)